# Can you control raspberry pi GPIO pins from a html website

Tags: gpio, software-installation, html5

I would like to be able to connect a html website to the GPIO pins so that when a button is pushed on the website it turns on a GPIO pin on the pi. I am also wondering if it is possible to take data from another GPIO pin and print it in the html website

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible with a website.

I have built something similar [here](https://github.com/JJandke/piled-server). It's about controlling a LED strip over the internet. I think you can take the sourcecode from it.

I wrote Python scripts to control the GPIOs. These Python scripts are called and executed by PHP scripts.
The PHP script is called with "execute" a URL (e.g. http://raspberrypi/poweron.php). This could be done by a button on your website.

**So this could be your Pyhton script:** (saved as: */home/pi/Code/App/power_on.py*)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)
logging.info("{0}Power on".format(log_time))
```

**And then your PHP script**

```
<?php

$command = escapeshellcmd('/home/pi/Code/App/power_on.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: thank you @jjandke for your help but when I go to the website http://raspberrypi/test_led_file.php, it will just sit there doing nothing, just a blank white screen. I have tested the code separately and it runs perfectly when run via Geaney.

Comment: Your script will run with the permissions of the web server which might not have permission to set GPIO pins. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39191/36775 for this. When you run it youself, the permissions used are your own and probably include the 'gpio' group which gives you access.

Comment: I think this page will help you: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40105/access-gpio-pins-without-root-no-access-to-dev-mem-try-running-as-root . As @patthoyts has already mentioned, the "www-data" user has no rights to /dev/mem.